# How to override makefile within a nested makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have 3 makefiles, say aa.mk, bb.mk and cc.mk, and I can edit cc.mk only.

bb.mk includes aa.mk.(using include stmt)

cc.mk includes bb.mk.(using include stmt)

So, in a sense cc.mk includes aa.mk also.
I want to edit cc.mk in a way that bb.mk is included but not aa.mk. In other words, I would like to know, if there is a way so that I can remove the reference being made to aa.mk from within cc.mk, without editing aa.mk or bb.mk.

Note: I have very limited knowledge of makefiles

Haven't been able to find any solution.

Need to include bb.mk without accessing aa.mk. The result prints values from aa.mk, whereas it should print values from cc.mk.

Comment: Just make a copy of bb.mk and edit it. Otherwise it's not possible, unless bb.mk already has some kind of predefined condition not to include aa.mk.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-include aa.mk` in cc.mk file.

```
include foo bb.mk bish bash
-include aa.mk
```

Comment: This does not do anything like what the question wanted.  `-include` does _NOT_ mean "un-include this file".

Comment: If you want make to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist or cannot be remade, with no error message, use the -include directive instead of include, like this:

-include filenames…

Comment: Sure but that's not what the question asked.  In this case the makefile definitely exists, and is included by `bb.mk`.  The ask is to allow `cc.mk` to avoid including `aa.mk` when `bb.mk` is included: _Need to include `bb.mk` without accessing `aa.mk`_